# How to read from a file and construct a two-dimensional array?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

Suppose a file `f` contains a rectangular list of integers, where the first line has the number of rows and columns of the integers in the file. For example:

```
3 5
2 5 4 8 9
8 5 8 5 7
1 2 3 5 4
```

What is the idiomatic way to read the file and construct a two-dimensional array?

Which will result in:

```
my_table = ((2, 5, 4, 8, 9), (8, 5, 8, 5, 7), (1, 2, 3, 5, 4))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you open the file for reading, you can use `next(..)` on the file itself to ignore the first line. After that use can use generator expression and pass it into a `tuple(..)` to create a tuple.

```
>> with open(yourFile) as f:
...     next(f)
...     a = tuple(tuple(int(y) for y in x.split()) for x in f)
... 
# a = ((2, 5, 4, 8, 9), (8, 5, 8, 5, 7), (1, 2, 3, 5, 4))
```

Comment: I find this answer more succinct.

Answer (score 1):

Well, basically you should open your file, discard the first line, and then construct your table using the rest of the file, and finally convert your list into a tuple since tuples are immutable and you cannot modify a tuple after you have created it:

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    f.readline() # ignores the first line
    table = []
    for line in f:
        table.append(tuple(int(e) for e in line.split()))

table = tuple(table)
```

You can also use a comprehension which will reduce your code notoriously:

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
        f.readline() # ignores the first line
        table = tuple(tuple(int(number) for number in line.split()) for line in f)
```